# How do I create a package of my javascript app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, npm

According my topic, what is the best way to distribute my javascript application? Is a best practice distribute my application using npm packages? Or npm is only for distribute frameworks?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are building with NodeJS APIs I see no reason why you wouldnt distribute your app with npm. See [here](http://decodize.com/javascript/build-nodejs-npm-installation-package-scratch/) for details on packaging and deploying which I found interesting.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to distribute JavaScript modules that were build on Node.js is to publish them onto *npm* with the command `npm publish`. You can find out how to properly publish modules in the official [documentation](https://npmjs.org/doc/developers.html).

Also read up on `package.json`. It is basically the interface that you can use for publications.